# mysql performs full table scan even though index exists

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, full-table-scan

so I have this table containt 100000 rows

```
field1 field2
```

now i Just added a new column field3 and moreover there is an index on field3

```
field1 field2 field3
```

so I added about 50 rows that contains field3 (the other rows have field3 as NULL)

so I do a select

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field3 IN (val1, val2);
```

an explain of that is fairly sane. It uses the index on field3 and only scans 2 rows

however as I add more values in the IN statement

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field3 IN (val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8, val9, val10);
```

This ends up not using the index and ends up performing a full table scan of the entire 100000+ rows.

why is mysql doing this? I know that mysql `"If you need to access most of the rows, it is faster to read sequentially, because this minimizes disk seeks."` from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html

but this can't possibly be faster than using the index to fetch those 10 values

why is mysql doing this and how can I instruct mysql to force them to use the index instead of performing full table scan...

Comment: Which storage engine (InnoDB, MyISAM or ?). Likely, MySQL's estimate of the index cardinality is different than you expect. Statistics are handled differently by MyISAM and InnoDB. [**myisam-index-statistics**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisam-index-statistics.html) [**innodb-statistics-estimation.html**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-statistics-estimation.html) Optimizer can be influenced by **hints** included in the statement [**index-hints**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-hints.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q:** Why is MySQL doing this?

**A:** Likely MySQL's estimate of the cardinality of the index is different than you expect, and MySQL is estimating that a full table scan is a more efficient plan than using the index.  There are ways to influence statistics, with both MyISAM and InnoDB. Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisam-index-statistics.html

**Q:** How can I instruct MySQL to force them to use the index?

**A:** You can try to influence statistics collection, so MySQL comes up with a different cardinality.

Or you can try including an index hint in the query text:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable FORCE INDEX myindex WHERE ...
```

Or, you could try re-writing the query as multiple SELECTs combined with UNION ALL set operator:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE field3 = val1
 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE field3 = val2
 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE field3 = val3
```